# don't show example in text view

Tags: java, android, xml, android-edittext, textview

i am write this code for my android app.

```
    btn =(Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
    et =(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);
    tv =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);

    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String name =et.getText().toString();
            String a = "a";
            String a1 = "ａ";
            String b = "b";
            String b1 = "ß";
            if(name.equals(a)){
             tv.setText(a1);

            }
            else if (name.equals(b)){
                tv.setText(b1);

            }
        }
    });

}
```

}

and write a in edit text don't show ａ in text view
and write b in edit text don't show ß in text view
please help

Comment: [How do I compare strings in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

Answer (score 1):

== is used to compare equality of two objects i.e, their name and hashcode.
Use equals or equalsIgnoreCase

```
name.equals("A")
```

or

```
name.equalsIgnoreCase("A")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (name.equals("A")){
    tv.setText("example");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply use

```
if(name.equalsIgnoreCase("A")) {
   tv.setText("example");
}
```